# Get the owner of an unsaved HABTM collection proxy in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Lets say I have two ActiveRecord classes:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :guardians
end

class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, inverse_of: :guardian

  before_validation :generate_username, on: :create

  def generate_username
    count = students.count
    self.username = 'g'+students.first.admission_no
  end

end
```

And the create function of my GuardiansController:

```
def create
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @guardian = @student.guardians.build(guardian_params)
    flash.now[:success] = 'Guardian was successfully created.' if @guardian.save
    respond_with(@guardian)
end
```

The `generate_username` function of the `Guardian` ActiveRecord Class fails because `students` returns an empty `Association CollectionProxy`.

How can I get the owner (student) of a Guardian before it is saved??

Comment: try to add the `inverse_of` on the other side of the relation too

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Did that, still returning an empty collection.

Comment: try `@student.build_guardian(guardian_params)` instead